# Facebook App with wildcard OAuth redirect URL

Tags: facebook, oauth

I have a Facebook app that I'm working on. In my app's advanced settings tab (in Facebook's developer site) I'd like to specify an OAuth redirect URL with a wildcard in it.

Each user of my app has a custom subdomain (e.g. `foobar.example.com`). I want to be able to specify an OAuth redirect url such as `*.example.com`.

I know for other platforms such as Twitter and LinkedIn, it's possible to achieve this by setting the redirect URL simply to example.com, and it will accept redirect URLs with any subdomain, including `www`. In my app's general settings tab I was able to change the url from `app.example.com` to `example.com`. After doing that, I can still authenticate from `app.example.com` and I am redirected back to `app.example.com/callback` because `app.example.com/callback` is whitelisted in my app settings.

If I try to authenticate from another subdomain such as `foobar.example.com`, I'm redirected back to `app.example.com/callback` afterwards, which is not what I want. I tried changing my redirect URL to `example.com`, as I did with the site url, but then I am redirect to `example.com/callback` instead of `app.example.com/callback`.

I've also tried using a wildcard such as `*.example.com/callback`, but Facebook wouldn't let me save the settings with a wildcard in the URL.

How can I make my redirect URL dynamic so that I don't need to manually enter hundreds or even thousands of whitelisted URLs?

Comment: You can’t. Valid OAuth Redirect URI field doesn’t allow wildcards.

Comment: Best you can perhaps do, is used one “main” domain to handle login, and then after the login flow is completed, redirect back to the “original” sub-domain the user came from.

Comment: I was looking into that as a fallback option, assuming I can at least pass parameters (e.g. the user's id) through.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add dynamic/wildcard FACEBOOK Valid OAuth redirect URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901020/add-dynamic-wildcard-facebook-valid-oauth-redirect-uris)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how to accomplish this in 4 simple steps:

1. Create a new subdomain for your app (e.g. auth.example.com).
2. In the settings tab for your Facebook app where you specify the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs, put in your new subdomain with the right path to your Oauth controller (e.g. https://auth.example.com/auth/facebook/callback).
3. When the user wants to authorize your app, send them to Facebook as normal and specify your new redirect url with their user ID (or some other identifier) as a parameter (e.g. https://auth.example.com/auth/facebook/callback?user_id=123).
4. When the user hits that redirect URI on your server, save their access token and then redirect them to wherever you want (e.g. back to https://foo.example.com).

My app has used this exact setup successfully for almost two years and we service thousands of users a day.

Comment: is this still possible to do now? I try to add a parameter to the callback URI and it throw me error about app domains

Comment: you better use the state param instead of custom param